# Out of memory exception System.Drawing.Image.FromFile

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

Here is my problem: I'm trying to open a file using server side code.

The file is 16,096KB and it's a rar file.

I also tried to open a file  7.14KB and which is an image file.

but when I'm running into that line of code it's throwing an error
**"Out Of Memeory"**

```
Dim img As System.Drawing.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(m_IRAttachmentsPath + AttachmentFileName)
```

Here is my code:

```
 If e.CommandName.ToString() = "OpenFile" Then
                Dim IRAttachmentsPath As String = Nothing
                Dim img As System.Drawing.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(m_IRAttachmentsPath + AttachmentFileName)
                Dim bytes As Byte()
                Using ms1 As New MemoryStream()
                    img.Save(ms1, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
                    bytes = ms1.ToArray()
                End Using

                Dim memStream As New MemoryStream()
                Dim Package As ZipPackage = ZipPackage.Create(memStream)

                Dim stream As Stream = New MemoryStream(bytes)
                Package.AddStream(stream, AttachmentFileName)
                SendZipToClient(memStream, Package)
End If



 Private Sub SendZipToClient(memStream As MemoryStream, Package As ZipPackage)
        Package.Close(False)
        memStream.Position = 0
        If memStream IsNot Nothing AndAlso memStream.Length > 0 Then
            Response.Clear()
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=photos.zip")
            Response.ContentType = "application/zip"
            Response.BinaryWrite(memStream.ToArray())
            Response.[End]()
        End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: A .rar file is not a .zip file, and whichever one it is you would have to decompress it to get the image file out before you can use it as an image file.

Comment: GDI+ (which is what's behind System.Drawing.Image) is a bit unhelpful with its error messages. "Out of memory" could simply mean that the file has an invalid format.

Comment: Are you sure that is the problem? if so how can I decompress it?

Comment: This is my path: C:/IRAttachments/GG/2014/9/IR-10808/IR-10808(1).rar and I double check the file is in that folder.

Comment: Try opening the file in something like Photoshop or Irfanview. If it complains that it is not a image file, then you know you need to research how to uncompress the file.

Comment: I tried that and it's complians that it's not an image.

Comment: Can anyone help me with the decompress function? Public Shared Sub Decompress(directoryPath As DirectoryInfo)
        For Each file As FileInfo In directoryPath.GetFiles()
            Dim path = directoryPath.FullName
            Dim zipPath As String = path + file.Name
            Dim extractPath As String = Regex.Replace(path + file.Name, ".zip", "")


        Next
    End Sub